# How to sort a string array as they are entered in Java without using the Array or Collection classes?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have to first take as input the number of strings to be sorted. As they are entered, I have to sort them in ascending order, not at the end. The first part came out fine, but I don't know how to sort them (preferred method per instructor is the compareto method) when I have nothing to compare until it's entered. I cannot use the Arrays class or Collection class, which means I have to work around it to test my ingenuity. 
Does anyone have any tips or pseudo code to lead me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.*;
```

public class Sort_as_Inserted {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");

   String element_number = input.nextLine();

   String[] user_word = new String[Integer.parseInt(element_number)];

   for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(element_number); i++)
   {
       System.out.print("Element " + (i + 1) + ": ");
       user_word[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println();



}//end Main Method
```

}//end Class

I am supposed to sort these elements as they are put in, not after (which makes it even more difficult for me). I cannot use anything in the Arrays class or Collection class to sort them. They have to be sorted in ascending order. So, if a user types "4" as the number of elements, then types "Cherry, Banana, Orange, Apple," it will output: "Apple, Banana, Cherry, Orange."

Comment: 1) paste your code you are having issues with. 2) Ask questions about specific parts you are having an issue with

Comment: paste the intial code before the downvote reaches to infinity.

Comment: Alright, the code is in the original post now, @Saint

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need Insertion Sort. Google it and try to understand the concept. Then try implementing it. Once you got that far you will probably have questions about specific parts where you struggle (if you'll struggle at all).

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @FrankAndres, I can't use Insertion Sort because I can't use anything from the java.util.Arrays class. There is a ton of information on the Arrays class in my Java books, all of which are of no use. Haha. I know how to compare strings after they are initialized, but they aren't initialized until the user types them in.

Comment: Insertion Sort is not about the java.util.Arrays class. It's an algorithm you can implement on your own. That's why I said you should try to understand the concept. It's not rocket science. I promise. :)

Comment: Oh cool. I'll look into it for sure. I touched on it briefly in my Discrete Structures course, so I'll see how to implement it into code.

Comment: How can I comment with my new code? It stated that it was too long by over 1,000 characters (yes I used the back ticks for formatting).

Comment: Thank you @FrankAndres. I'm still learning how to use this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I got it and it worked as intended. It took some thinking, but it's done. I wanted to post my completed code for future questions from others.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Sort_as_Inserted {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter number of elements to be sorted: ");

   int array_size = input.nextInt();

   String[] user_words = new String [array_size];

   input.nextLine();

   for (int i = 0; i < user_words.length; i++)
   {
       System.out.print("Element " + (i + 1) + ": ");
       user_words[i] = input.nextLine();

    }//end for
    System.out.println();

    sortStrings(user_words);
    printTheArray(user_words);

 }//end Main
```

public static void sortStrings(String[] words) {

```
 /**
  * This method will utilize an Insertion Sort Algorithm
  */  
 for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
 {
     for(int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++)
     {
         if(words[i].compareToIgnoreCase(words[j]) > 0)
         {
             String temp = words[i];
             words[i] = words[j];
             words[j] = temp;
         }//end if
     }//end inner for
 }//end outer for
```

}//end sortSTrings Method

```
public static void printTheArray(String[] the_words) {

    /**
     * This following code block will print the array, and format it properly
     * so there is no comma after the last word in the array. 
     */


    if (the_words.length >= 1) 
    {
        System.out.print(the_words[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < the_words.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(", " + the_words[i]);
    }

}//end printTheArray Method
```

}//end Sort_As_Inserted Class